# How to pre-process transactional data to predict probability to buy?

Tags: python, r, pandas, scikit-learn, prediction

I'm working on a model for a departament store that uses data from previous purchases to predict the customer's probability to buy today. For the sake of simplicity, say that we have 3 categories of products (A, B, C) and I want to use the purchase history of the customers in Q1, Q2 and Q3 2017 to predict the probability to buy in Q4 2017.

How should I structure my indicators file?

**My try:**

The variables I want to predict are the red colored cells in the production set.

[image]

Please note the following:

- Since my set of customers is the same for both years, I'm using a photo of how customers acted last year to predict what will they do at the end of this year (which is unknown).
- Data is separated by trimester, a co-worker sugested this is not correct, because I'm unintentionally giving greater weight to the indicators splitting each one in 4, when they should only be one per category.

**Alternative:**

Another aproach I was sugested was to use two indicators per category: Ex.'bought_in_category_A' and 'days_since_bought_A'. For me this looks simpler, but then the model will only be able to predict IF the customer will buy Y, not WHEN they will buy Y. Also, what will happen if the customer never bought A? I cannot use a 0 since that will imply customers who never bought are closer to customers who just bought a few days ago.

**Questions:**

1. Is this structure ok or would you structure the data in another way?
2. Is it ok to use information from last year in this case?
3. Is it ok to 'split' a cateogorical variable into several binary variables? does this affect the importance given to that variable?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you need a different approach in order to achieve predictive analysis.

- For example the products' properties are unknown here (color, taste,
  size, seasonality,....)
- There is no information about the customers
  (age, gender, living area etc...)
- You need more "transactional"
  information, (when, why - how did they buy etc......)
- What is the products "lifecycle"? Does it have to do with fashion?
- What branch are you in? (Retail, Bulk, Finance, Clothing...)
- Meanwhile have you done any campaign? How will this be measured?

I would first (if applicable) concetrate on the categories relations and behaviour for each Quarter:
For example When n1 decreases then n2 decreases
when q1 is lower than q2 or q1/2016 vs q2/2017.

I think you should first of all, work this out with a business analyst in order to to find out the right "rules" and approach.

I do no think you could get a concrete answer with these generic-assumed data.
Usually you need data from at least 3-5 recent years to do some descent predictive analysis, depending of course, on the nature of your product.
Hope, this helped a bit.

;-)

-mwk

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I do have all that information: product atributes (color, size, etc), demographic information (age, gender, location), etc. since 2013. This was an oversimplitication to make it understandable. I was more concerned about how seasonality affected the way I structured my information, but you do answered my question stating I could separate the info in quarters.